# How do I use python to get the dimensions of a text object immediately after it is created?

Tags: python, dimensions

I'm creating a text object using Python and I'd like to do a non-standard align (something other than left/right/center).  To accomplish this I need the dimensions, but the dimensions.x is 0 at the time the python is running.  It becomes non-zero later

```
import bpy

name = "text1"

t1 = bpy.data.curves.new(name, 'FONT')
o1 = bpy.data.objects.new(name, t1)
o1.location = (0,0,2)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(o1)

t1.body = "Hail Bob!"

c1 = o1.constraints.new('TRACK_TO')
c1.target = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
c1.track_axis = 'TRACK_Z'
c1.up_axis = 'UP_Y'

if False:
    t1.align = 'RIGHT'
else:
    print (o1.dimensions.x)
    t1.text_boxes[0].x = o1.dimensions.x * -0.3
```

Is there a blender API that will trigger a calculation of the dimensions property of the object so that I can use it before returning control to the UI?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there's no `.update()` method for Curve objects, you need to trigger a scene update:

```
t1.body = "Hail Bob!"
bpy.context.scene.update()
print(o1.dimensions)
```

Result:

```
<Vector (3.6080, 0.7000, 0.0000)>
```

Comment: For 2.80: `bpy.context.view_layer.update()`